# Cannot use Set to filter RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to filter an RDD using a Set.

I have an RDD that's an array of Objects (Fruit: String, Value: Int, Color: String) that I want to filter out using a Set that contains some Fruit value.

When I try to filter using the filter

```
val Fruits = Set("Orange","Banana","Strawberry")
<rddname>.filter(line => line.Fruit.contains(Fruits))
```

I keep getting the error Task not serializable. What does it mean?

I've also tried

```
<rddname>.filter(line => Fruits(line.Fruit))
```

Same error

Comment: its simply means that Fruits variable is defined in the driver node and is not serialized and distributed to executors. One simple solution is to broadcast Fruits set or define Fruits set on each executor

Comment: What does that mean? I'm still very new to Scala

Comment: search in stackoverflow on how to broadcast and you will find a lot of answers